# Could we view questions with unaccepted answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was browsing the MySQL tag and looking at the unanswered questions to see if I could solve any, when a thought occured to me that I can only filter on unanswered questions:
[image]

Would it be plausible to have an option to filter on questions with answers that have not yet been accepted? If a user asks a question that gets an answer (though not the one they need) and this question does not get enough attention it could be lost forever (without offering a bounty).

There's no way for someone like me to find that question, where as I could find their question without any answers by browsing unanswered.

Comment: You can make such a filter on the search page if you're suitably motivated.  Also note "unanswered" means no answer with a positive score, not no answers at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unanswered tab and  unanswered button above it are already close to what you want as it will show questions that do not have an accepted answer, as well as questions with answers that do not have any upvotes.

> [image]

However, exactly what you want is already available using the [Advanced Search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) options.

Just enter `answers:1 hasaccepted:0` into the search bar and you will get questions that have at least 1 answer and do not yet have an accepted answer.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that existed, or that we could filter on that. For my example: `answers:1 hasaccepted:0 [mysql]` gave me exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the last page of the "unanswered" tab, you'll see that it does include questions that have answers but where none are accepted or have a positive score. It just sorts those questions later than questions that don't have any answers at all.

An easier way to see questions in a tag that have answers but where none are accepted is to use [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). For example, try searching for `[mysql] answers:1 hasaccepted:no`.